# Problems with JBoss and ProxyPass Apache directive

Tags: apache, jboss, jboss7.x, mod-proxy, mod-jk

My JBoss 7.1 (standalone.xml) is configured like this:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
            <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
            <connector name="ajp" protocol="AJP/1.3" scheme="http" socket-binding="ajp"/>
            <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="false" default-web-module="mydefaultapp">
                <alias name="localhost"/>
                <alias name="www.mydefaultapp.it"/>
            </virtual-server>
            <virtual-server name="secondApp" enable-welcome-root="false" default-web-module="secondApp">
                <alias name="www.secondapp.com"/>
            </virtual-server>
        </subsystem>
```

'mydefaultapp' defines "/" as context-root in jboss-web.xml file and is running perfectly with mod_jk:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName      www.mydefaultapp.it

        DocumentRoot /var/www/mydefaultapp
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/mydefaultapp>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SetEnvIf Request_URI "/foto/*" no-jk
        JkMount / ajp13
        JkMount /* ajp13

</VirtualHost>
```

Now I have that 'secondapp' war which doesn't define a context-root so it assumes '/secondapp'. If I try to deploy it with '/' context-root I get this error:

> INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "foo.war"
>   Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service
>   jboss.web.deployment.default-host./.realm is already registered

If I deploy it with '/secondapp' context-root nothing works. Simply www.secondapp.com ends in 404 not found error.

A possible solution would be using http proxy with this configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.secondapp.com
    ProxyPass         /     http://localhost:8080/secondapp/
    ProxyPassReverse  /     http://localhost:8080/secondapp/
</VirtualHost>
```

which seems working but... I can't access jsf resources (I keep getting login form, there's some problem with my security)

Can you please suggest me the right configuration for having two domains, two wars with JBoss 7.1 + Apache2 + mod_jk. Remember the first one has "/" context-root while the second one has "/secondapp"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I made it with mod_jk! It's about  tag, it's confusing. I blogged about that: http://fabiobozzo.wordpress.com/2013/02/25/multiple-web-applications-with-jboss-and-apache/